# Making a global variable accessible for every function inside a class

Tags: php, class, function, variables, global

I have a variable on the global scope that is named `${SYSTEM}`, where SYSTEM is a defined constant. I've got a lot of classes with functions that need to have access to this variable and I'm finding it annoying declaring `global ${SYSTEM};` every single time.

I tried declaring a class variable: `public ${SYSTEM} = $GLOBALS[SYSTEM];` but this results in a syntax error which is weird because I have another class that declares class variables in this manner and seems to work fine. The only thing I can think of is that the constant isn't being recognised.

I have managed to pull this off with a constructor but I'm looking for a simpler solution before resorting to that.

---

**EDIT**
The global ${SYSTEM} variable is an array with a lot of other child arrays in it. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to get around using a constructor...

Answer (score 8):

Ok, hopefully I've got the gist of what you're trying to achieve

```
<?php
    // the global array you want to access
    $GLOBALS['uname'] = array('kernel-name' => 'Linux', 'kernel-release' => '2.6.27-11-generic', 'machine' => 'i686');

    // the defined constant used to reference the global var
    define(_SYSTEM_, 'uname');

    class Foo {

        // a method where you'd liked to access the global var  
        public function bar() {
            print_r($this->{_SYSTEM_});
        }

        // the magic happens here using php5 overloading
        public function __get($d) {
            return $GLOBALS[$d];  
        }

    }

    $foo = new Foo;
    $foo->bar();

?>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is how I access things globally without global.

```
class exampleGetInstance 
{

private static $instance;

public $value1;
public $value2;


private function initialize() 
{
    $this->value1 = 'test value';
    $this->value2 = 'test value2';

}

public function getInstance()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
    {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $class();
        self::$instance->initialize();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

}

$myInstance = exampleGetInstance::getInstance();

echo $myInstance->value1;
```

`$myInstance` is now a reference to the instance of `exampleGetInstance` class.

Fixed formatting

Answer (score 2):

You could use a constructor like this:

```
class Myclass {
  public $classvar; 
  function Myclass() {
    $this->classvar = $GLOBALS[SYSTEM];
  }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for pointing out the typo, Peter!

This works for array too. If assignment is not desired, taking the reference also works:

```
$this->classvar =& $GLOBALS[SYSTEM];
```

EDIT2: The following code was used to test this method and it worked on my system:

```
<?php
define('MYCONST', 'varname');
$varname = array("This is varname", "and array?");

class Myclass {
  public $classvar;
  function Myclass() {
    $this->classvar =& $GLOBALS[MYCONST];
  }
  function printvar() {
    echo $this->classvar[0]; 
    echo $this->classvar[1];
  }
};

$myobj = new Myclass;
$myobj->printvar();
?>
```

Comment: Should that be '$this->classvar = ...'?

Answer (score 1):

The direct specification of member variables can not contain any references to other variables (`class {public $membervar = $outsidevar;}` is invalid as well). Use a constructor instead.

However, as you are dealing with a constant, why don't you use php's [constant](http://php.net/define) or [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) facilities?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do something really out-of-the-ordinary here, so you can expect it to be awkward. Working with globals is never pleasant, especially not with your dynamic name selection using `SYSTEM` constant. Personally I'd recommend you use `$GLOBALS[SYSTEM]` everywhere instead, or ...

```
$sys = $GLOBALS[SYSTEM];
```

... if you're going to use it alot.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try the singleton pattern, although to some degree it is frowned upon in OOP circles, it is commonly referred to as the global variable of classes.

```
<?php
class Singleton {

  // object instance
  private static $instance;

  // The protected construct prevents instantiating the class externally.  The construct can be
  // empty, or it can contain additional instructions...
  protected function __construct() {
    ...
  }

  // The clone and wakeup methods prevents external instantiation of copies of the Singleton class,
  // thus eliminating the possibility of duplicate objects.  The methods can be empty, or
  // can contain additional code (most probably generating error messages in response
  // to attempts to call).
  public function __clone() {
    trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
  }

  public function __wakeup() {
    trigger_error('Deserializing is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
  }

  //This method must be static, and must return an instance of the object if the object
  //does not already exist.
  public static function getInstance() {
    if (!self::$instance instanceof self) { 
      self::$instance = new self;
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  //One or more public methods that grant access to the Singleton object, and its private
  //methods and properties via accessor methods.
  public function GetSystemVar() {
    ...
  }
}

//usage
Singleton::getInstance()->GetSystemVar();

?>
```

This example is slightly modified from wikipedia, but you can get the idea. Try googling the singleton pattern for more information

Comment: I don't see how this is related to singleton.

Comment: How doesn't it relate? An explanation would seem more appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say the first two things that stand out to me are:

1. You don't need the brackets around the variable name, you can simply do public $system or public $SYSTEM.
2. While PHP may not always require it it is standard practice to encapsulate non-numeric array indexes in single or double quotes in case the string you're using becomes a constant at some point.

This should be what you're looking for

```
class SomeClass {
  public $system = $GLOBALS['system'];
}
```

You can also use class constants which would instead be

```
class SomeClass {
  const SYSTEM = $GLOBALS['system'];
}
```

This can be referenced within the class with 'self::SYSTEM' and externally with 'SomeClass::SYSTEM'.

Comment: Does that mean constants > variable names?

Comment: In the question, SYSTEM is a constant, not a variable name.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about but ${SYSTEM} most definitely isn't the same as $SYSTEM...

Comment: @E3, are you referring to my comment? I was saying that Steven probably had mistaken SYSTEM as a variable.