# How to get value in function that is retrived and stored in a variable of another function in same class | Magento 2

Tags: php, variables, magento2

**Edit:**
I want to use $orderId value in other functions.

Here is class

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) { 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    }

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
   }
public function getOrderId(){

    $Id = $orderId;
    return $Id;
}
```

}

I tried this:

```
class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
public $orderId;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) { 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    }

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        this->$orderId = $order->getId();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
   }
public function getOrderId(){

    $Id = this->$orderId;
    return $Id;
}
}
```

I am Calling getOrderId(); in same class.. but not working

Gone through links like [Making a global variable accessible for every function inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519078/making-a-global-variable-accessible-for-every-function-inside-a-class)
Need a solution in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more about [Object Oriented Concepts](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm) to understand what is Class, Object, Member variables, Member functions etc

Magento2 has a function to get last order id here:

```
$orderId = $this->checkout->getLastOrderId();
```

with $this->checkout is an instantiation of CheckoutSession

Regards